# Outlook 2013 - AutoArchive folder settings (permanently delete) not being observed

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013

I have Outlook 2013 on Windows 10 connecting to an Exchange mailbox (running Exchange 2016).

By default I don't archive e-mails.  I have a set of folders (contained under the same root folder) that I want to deleted e-mails according to custom ages per folder.  I have set these folders up with custom archive properties.

**My problem is that when autoarchive runs the archive rules are not observed and no e-mails in scope are deleted.**

My settings are as follows:

```
- Mailbox (default archive settings)
+- Notifications folder (default archive settings)
 +- Subfolder 1 (custom settings - delete anything older than 7 days)
 +- Subfolder 2 (custom settings - delete anything older than 3 months)
```

Default Autoarchive settings on the mailbox:

[image: Default AutoArchive settings on the mailbox]

In the root of the mailbox I have a folder called Notifications - settings are as follows:

[image: Notifications folder settings]

Under Notifications, I have several subfolders, each with their own archive settings, e.g.:

[image: Notifications subfolder archive settings - permanently delete e-mail]

In the example above, when I run AutoArchive, I would expect the subfolder above to no longer have any e-mails in it that are older than 7 days.  This is not the case (e-mails from months ago are in there).

Am I interpreting the AutoArchive functionality wrongly?  I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

**Update (2019-03-11)**

I have been playing around with settings and have made the change below to Default settings on the mailbox.

[image: Default Archive Settings with "Archive or delete old items" ticked]

I then set up Notifications with "Archive items in this folder using the default settings"

The subfolder age settings are then picked up, but **in-scope items are moved to the archive file and not permanently deleted**, despite this being the setting on the subfolder properties.

At the moment I can live with the items I've asked to be permanently deleted being moved to the archive folder, but it is frustrating that this setting is not being observed - **is this a known bug in Outlook 2013?**

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it is still a problem in 2022 with Office 365.  Thanks for this article.  I was attempting to do exactly what you were and running into the same problem.  I stumbled across this post after going through pages of links and trying dozens of other "fixes".  Your workaround worked for me.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

According [this KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2553550/how-to-change-the-criteria-that-outlook-2010-and-outlook-2013-use-to-a), by default AutoArchive feature checks the received date or the last modified date and time, whichever is later.

I think you could try to add the registry “ArchiveIgnoreLastModifiedTime” under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Preferences, restart the machine and then check if it would work. You could do manually archive via “File” – “Cleanup Tools” – “Archive”.

Comment: Hi @Shaw - thanks for the reply and advice.  I have tried this out and still no joy I'm afraid.  I've double checked the last modified date on the items just in case.  Thanks again for taking the time to reply.